# How can I tell which citrus plant it is from their leaves?

Tags: identification, citrus

A few years ago I planted a variety of seeds from citrus fruits of orange, lemon, lime, grapefruit and mandarine. Only a few of them grew into big plants, and now I have 2-4 large plants, but I don't know which of them are which. Can I tell from the shapes of the leaves which citrus plant it is?

Here's a group photo with some unidentified bonus plant in the middle:

[image]

The two on the left are growing from the same spot, so they could be from the same seed. And the unknown guest plant in front is growing from the same pot. The more bushy guy on the right has its pot all to himself. After some image searching and seeing similar leaves on posts about citrus plants, I figured that the mystery plant could also be a citrus, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Break a leaf off, snap it in half and smell it. This will help with one more characteristic to narrow it down.

Comment: They all smell pretty citrusy to me but not exactly like a lemon, orange or grapefruit. It's a bit different and I can't tell exactly what it's like.

Answer (score 1):

Although I suspect it will be very tough to do, the [Citrus ID](http://idtools.org/id/citrus/citrusid/morphology.php?state%5B%5D=leaves) web page might be your best resource outside a citrus farmer/fanatic.

Answer (score 1):

just signed I'm from Tanzania. Found a couple of citrus plant outside my bedrooms window as I was "googling" for ID I came across, "orange leaves grow in a compound arrangement, with multiple leaves arising from a single bud. Lemon leaves have jagged edges, and the branches of the trees bear thorns. Oranges may or may not have toothed leaves"

Comment: So are these neither, according to your descriptions?

Comment: That's right. I'm curious to know. It's rainy season here the right time to plant.